# Power Query Date format issue

Tags: excel, powerquery

I use Powerquery to extract from database using sql, when i am in the editor it displays normal, but when i close and load, the format changes to a strange format

Example
in powerquery editor window display is 6/28/2021 5:21:38pm
in excel it changes to 44200.68331

so everytime i have to manualy change the format back.

anyone know what date format this is, and how i can have it automatically save the format from the editor screen to excel?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyBN3.png)

thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know why PowerQuery is doing that, but the date is just the number representation of the date. June 28, 2021 is 44,200 days since 1 Jan 1900. That's the date Excel considers day 0. The decimal part represents the time which is a fraction of a day.

Comment: Do you have any additional steps that may change the column data type?  Post your M Code from the Advanced Editor.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.